# SO Application Instructions

Tags: bug, status-completed

On the [hiring](https://stackoverflow.com/about/hiring) page there are two different sets of instructions for applicants.

Set the first:

> There is only one way to apply for
>   these jobs:
>
> 1. Make a CV on Stack Overflow Careers—it's free.
> 2. Email the URL of your CV to jobs@stackoverflow.com
> 3. Enjoy a tasty beverage and take the rest of the day off. You earned it.

Set the second:

> If you recognize yourself in this, we want to talk to you: please send the link to your CV, a cover letter and a pitch for stackoverflow.com's job listings to jobs@stackoverflow.com

Cover Letter/No Cover Letter, Pitch/No Pitch, Tasty Beverage/No Tasty Beverage...my head hurts.

Comment: **Always** tasty beverage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For people who want to be account executives, we ask them to also send "a pitch for stackoverflow.com's job listings" as a part of their application package.

The page will be updated to say

> NOTE: If you are applying for the position of account executive, in addition to the link to your CV, please write up a sample sales pitch email, pitching a job listing on jobs.stackoverflow.com, and include that with your application

Answer (score 7):

### SO Application Instructions

Follow instructions below carefully for best results:

1. Apply small amount of SO in an inconspicuous area to ensure there are no undesired effects.
2. Apply thin layer of SO.
3. Wait 20 minutes and apply another thin layer.
4. Repeat until desired consistency and color is reached.

<sub>**Caution: Harmful or fatal if swallowed.** If SO gets in eyes, flush with pure water. Do not allow small children access to SO. May contain products known to the State of California to cause cancer.</sub>

Comment: **OH GOD IT BURNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNSSSSSSSSS AHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHAHAHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH!!**

Comment: @Jon Seigel: That's the funny thing about SO.  If you apply too thin a layer it ends up burning off the first six layers of skin...someone should definitely put that in the next version of the instructions.

Comment: Oops, I forgot a step.

Comment: Do not taunt SO.